# React Navigation Authentation Flow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I configured my Navigators as follows:

**App.js**

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator ({Home: HomeScreen});
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ Login: Login},{ headerMode: 'none' });

    export default createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            App: AppStack,
            Auth: AuthStack
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'Auth',
        }
    );
```

The Login can be three different component: Username/Password, Pincode, Fingerprint. In the Login component i use conditional rendering for show te right screen:

**Login.js**

```
if(){
  return(<Fingerprint navigation={this.props.navigation}}/>)
} else if (){
  return(<Password navigation={this.props.navigation}/>)
} else if (){
  return(<Pincode navigation={this.props.navigation}}/>)
}
```

When i want to switch between this components i used **setState()** so the Login.js can re-render and show the right screen based on the if-else if statement in the code section above.

Now i my question, is this the right implementation with performance in mind? For example when I wanna show Pincode instead of Fingerprint, the Fingerprint doesn't need to stay in the background.

Hope i'm clear and thanks for any answer.

Comment: When you re-render a page and if you aren’t returning your unwanted component in render method, that will not be rendered. So you can simply use whatever method you are currently trying keeping in mine not to return unwanted element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I wanna show Pincode instead of Fingerprint, the Fingerprint
>   doesn't need to stay in the background.

It won't stay in the background. You can try it yourself, it will be fun. Try writing the following methods in each Component class

```
class Fingerprint extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Fingerprint mounted");
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("Fingerprint unmounted");
    }
    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And hopefully you will be able to appreciate what React does under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a `switch` called from `render`?

```
returnComponent(identifier){
    switch(identifier){
        case 'fingerprint':
            return <Fingerprint navigation={this.props.navigation}}/>
            break;
        case 'password':
            return <Password navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
            break;
        case 'pin':
            return <Pincode navigation={this.props.navigation}}/>
            break;
        default:
            return null;
            break;
    }
}
render(){
    const {identifier} = this.props
    return (
        <div>
            {this.returnComponent(identifier)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what happens when i switch between this component in the background?